# Aframe texture control over individual entities

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

I was wondering how to set a texture on an entity but only that entity and then be able to place more by selecting texture buttons I can't get my code to work properly but I wanted to make it function a little more like minecraft than the original minecraft aframe demo did. If anybody can get my code to work it would be a real help. All the script that is commented out was because I wanted to find a better way to do whatever I was trying. Essentially I want to pick a texture in the menu at the bottom and then use that texture on my entities.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-controller-cursor-component@0.2.x/dist/aframe-controller-cursor-component.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /**
 * Snap entity to the closest interval specified by `snap`.
 * Offset entity by `offset`.
 */
AFRAME.registerComponent('snap', {
  dependencies: ['position'],

  schema: {
    offset: {type: 'vec3'},
    snap: {type: 'vec3'}
  },

  init: function () {
    this.originalPos = this.el.getAttribute('position');
  },

  update: function () {
    const data = this.data;

    const pos = AFRAME.utils.clone(this.originalPos);
    pos.x = Math.floor(pos.x / data.snap.x) * data.snap.x + data.offset.x;
    pos.y = Math.floor(pos.y / data.snap.y) * data.snap.y + data.offset.y;
    pos.z = Math.floor(pos.z / data.snap.z) * data.snap.z + data.offset.z;

    this.el.setAttribute('position', pos);
  }
});
    </script>
<script>/**
 * Spawn entity at the intersection point on click, given the properties passed.
 *
 * `<a-entity intersection-spawn="mixin: box; material.color: red">` will spawn
 * `<a-entity mixin="box" material="color: red">` at intersection point.
 */
AFRAME.registerComponent('intersection-spawn', {
  schema: {
    default: '',
    parse: AFRAME.utils.styleParser.parse
  },

  init: function () {
    const data = this.data;
    const el = this.el;

    el.addEventListener(data.event, evt => {
      // Create element. (element create     below v
      const spawnEl = document.createElement('a-entity');

      // Snap intersection point to grid and offset from center. (position)
      spawnEl.setAttribute('position', evt.detail.intersection.point);

      // Set components and properties.
      Object.keys(data).forEach(name => {
        if (name === 'event') { return; }
        AFRAME.utils.entity.setComponentProperty(spawnEl, name, data[name]);
      });

      // Append to scene.
      el.sceneEl.appendChild(spawnEl);
    });
  }
});</script>
    <script>
     function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 10,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
    </script>
    <style>
      .transparentBox {
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #6969697a;
        margin-right: 600px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
      
      html {
       width: 800px;
       height: 600px;
       cursor: crosshair;
      }
      
      a-scene {
        cursor: crosshair;
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
      }
     
      body {
        cursor: crosshair;
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
      }
 
      .Container {
        margin-right: 8px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    <!-- aframe overlay -->
    
    <div class="Container" style="position:relative;">
   <!-- <a-scene id="updateMe" inspector="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe-inspector@master/dist/aframe-inspector.min.js"> -->
      <a-scene embedded>
      <a-assets>
      <img id="groundTexture" src="floor.jpg">
      <img id="skyTexture" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/a-painter/images/sky.jpg">
      
        <a-mixin id="voxel1"
         geometry="primitive: box; height: 0.6; width: 0.6; depth: 0.6"
         material="id: theImage; src: Box.jpg; color: #696969; roughness: 1; metalness: 0"     
         snap="offset: 0.4 0.4 0.4; snap: 0.6 0.6 0.6"
      ></a-mixin>
        <a-mixin id="voxel2"
         geometry="primitive: box; height: 0.6; width: 0.6; depth: 0.6"
         material="id: theImage; src: Brick.jpg; color: #696969; roughness: 1; metalness: 0"     
         snap="offset: 0.4 0.4 0.4; snap: 0.6 0.6 0.6"
      ></a-mixin>
        <a-mixin id="voxel3"
         geometry="primitive: box; height: 0.6; width: 0.6; depth: 0.6"
         material="id: theImage; src: Steel.jpg; color: #696969; roughness: 1; metalness: 0"     
         snap="offset: 0.4 0.4 0.4; snap: 0.6 0.6 0.6"
      ></a-mixin>
        <a-mixin id="voxel4"
         geometry="primitive: box; height: 0.6; width: 0.6; depth: 0.6"
         material="id: theImage; src: Pcb.jpg; color: #696969; roughness: 1; metalness: 0"     
         snap="offset: 0.4 0.4 0.4; snap: 0.6 0.6 0.6"
      ></a-mixin>
        <a-mixin id="voxel5"
         geometry="primitive: box; height: 0.6; width: 0.6; depth: 0.6"
         material="id: theImage; src: Grass.jpg; color: #696969; roughness: 1; metalness: 0"     
         snap="offset: 0.4 0.4 0.4; snap: 0.6 0.6 0.6"
      ></a-mixin>
        <a-mixin id="voxel6"
         geometry="primitive: box; height: 0.6; width: 0.6; depth: 0.6"
         material="id: theImage; src: Ice.jpg; color: #696969; roughness: 1; metalness: 0"     
         snap="offset: 0.4 0.4 0.4; snap: 0.6 0.6 0.6"
      ></a-mixin>
        <a-mixin id="voxel7"
         geometry="primitive: box; height: 0.6; width: 0.6; depth: 0.6"
         material="id: theImage; src: Fabric.jpg; color: #696969; roughness: 1; metalness: 0"     
         snap="offset: 0.4 0.4 0.4; snap: 0.6 0.6 0.6"
      ></a-mixin>
        
    </a-assets>
   <a-obj-model rotation="-90 45 0" position="0 2 0" src="tinker.obj" mtl="obj.mtl"></a-obj-model>
    <a-cylinder id="ground" src="#groundTexture" radius="30" height="0.1"></a-cylinder>

    <a-sky id="background" src="#skyTexture" theta-length="90" radius="30"></a-sky>

    <!-- Camera. -->
    <a-camera fly="true" position="0 0.75 15" wasd-controls="acceleration: 20" wasd-controls-enabled="true" fov="90" reverse-mouse-drag="false">
      <a-cursor id="Save1" intersection-spawn="event: click; mixin: voxel1"></a-cursor>
      <a-cursor id="Save2" intersection-spawn="event: click; mixin: voxel2"></a-cursor>
      <a-cursor id="Save3" intersection-spawn="event: click; mixin: voxel3"></a-cursor>
      <a-cursor id="Save4" intersection-spawn="event: click; mixin: voxel4"></a-cursor>
      <a-cursor id="Save5" intersection-spawn="event: click; mixin: voxel5"></a-cursor>
      <a-cursor id="Save6" intersection-spawn="event: click; mixin: voxel6"></a-cursor>
      <a-cursor id="Save7" intersection-spawn="event: click; mixin: voxel7"></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
      </a-scene>
      <!-- /aframe overlay -->
      <center>
      <div style="position:absolute; margin-right:8px; top:0px; width:205px; height:180px; left:0px; z-index:1000;">
        <div class="transparentBox">
        <b><h1 color="#FFFFFF" id="time">10:00</h1></b>
          <p style="font-size:20px;font-family:monospace;margin-top:-20px;">Camera Height:</p>
          <h1><b><a>&uarr;</a>~~<a>&darr;</a></b></h1>
          <iframe src="250-milliseconds-of-silence.mp3" allow="autoplay" id="audio" style="display:none"></iframe>
          <audio autoplay loop id="track">
  <source src="Magic_Scout_-_Cottages.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio><center>
          <button class="button" id="myBtn">Menu</button>
          </center>
        </div>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <center>
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="startTimer()" class="close">&times;</span>
    <center>
      <p class="beginMenuText"><b>Welcome to SandBox!</b></p>
      <p class="Text">WASD to move, Space place blocks.</p>
      <p class="Text2">You have 10 min. before the game restarts and all is lost.</p>
      <p class="Text2point5">Have fun...</p>
    </center>
    <p class="Text3"><b><u>Credits:</u></b></p>
    <p class="Text4">All music by <b>Kevin MacLeod</b></p>
    <p class="Text5"><b>Aframe</b> by the Aframe authors.</p>
    <p class="Text6">(Licenced under the <b>MIT Licence</b>)</p>
    <p class="Text7">Inspiration from other <b>WebVR Projects.</b></p>
    <p class="Text8">Voxel textures can be changed using the menu at the <b>bottom</b>.</p>
    <p class="Text9"><b>Enjoy!</b></p>
    <div class="unmute" onclick="document.getElementById('track').muted = !document.getElementById('track').muted;$(this).toggleClass('mute')"></div>
  </div>
          </center>
        </div>
          <div class="textureMenu">
            <div class="textureBox" id="Kill1" ><img src="Box.jpg" height="45" width="45"></div>
             <p class="spacer">~</p>
            <div class="textureBox" id="Kill2"><img src="Brick.jpg" height="45" width="45"></div>
             <p class="spacer">~</p>
            <div class="textureBox" id="Kill3"><img src="Steel.jpg" height="45" width="45"></div>
             <p class="spacer">~</p>
            <div class="textureBox" id="Kill4"><img src="Pcb.jpg" height="45" width="45"></div>
             <p class="spacer">~</p>
            <div class="textureBox" id="Kill5"><img src="Grass.jpg" height="45" width="45"></div>
             <p class="spacer">~</p>
            <div class="textureBox" id="Kill6"><img src="Ice.jpg" height="45" width="45"></div>
             <p class="spacer">~</p>
            <div class="textureBox" id="Kill7"><img src="Fabric.jpg" height="45" width="45"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </center>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>                  
  <head>
   <!--<script>
document.getElementById('Kill1').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var mixinEl = document.getElementById('Save1');
  if (mixinEl.getAttribute('mixin') === 'voxel') {
    mixinEl.setAttribute('mixin',: 'voxel1');
  }
};
</script>
    <script>
document.getElementById('Kill2').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var mixinEl = document.getElementById('Save2');
  if (mixinEl.getAttribute('mixin') === 'voxel') {
    mixinEl.setAttribute('mixin',: 'voxel2');
  }
};
</script>
    <script>
document.getElementById('Kill3').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var mixinEl = document.getElementById('Save3');
  if (mixinEl.getAttribute('mixin') === 'voxel') {
    mixinEl.setAttribute('mixin',: 'voxel3');
  }
};
</script>
    <script>
document.getElementById('Kill4').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var mixinEl = document.getElementById('Save4');
  if (mixinEl.getAttribute('mixin') === 'voxel') {
    mixinEl.setAttribute('mixin',: 'voxel4');
  }
};
</script>
    <script>
document.getElementById('Kill5').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var mixinEl = document.getElementById('Save5');
  if (mixinEl.getAttribute('mixin') === 'voxel') {
    mixinEl.setAttribute('mixin',: 'voxel5');
  }
};
</script>
    <script>
document.getElementById('Kill6').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var mixinEl = document.getElementById('Save6');
  if (mixinEl.getAttribute('mixin') === 'voxel') {
    mixinEl.setAttribute('mixin',: 'voxel6');
  }
};
</script>
    <script>
document.getElementById('Kill7').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var mixinEl = document.getElementById('Save7');
  if (mixinEl.getAttribute('mixin') === 'voxel') {
    mixinEl.setAttribute('mixin',: 'voxel7');
  }
};
</script>-->

    <style>
      .spacer {
        float: left;
      }
      .textureBox {
        width: 47px;
        height: 47px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        float: left;
      }
      .textureMenu {
        height: 50px;
        width: 412px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #6969697a;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        display:inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 200%;
        top: 313%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
      .Text9 {
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: monospace;
        margin-top: -13px;
        border-bottom: 2px dashed black;
      }
      .Text8 {
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: monospace;
        margin-top: -13px;
      }
      .Text7 {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: monospace;
        margin-top: -13px;
        border-bottom: 2px dashed black;
        
      }
      .Text6 {
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: monospace;
        margin-top: -20px;
        line-height: 1.3;
      }
      .Text5 {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: monospace;
        margin-top: -22px;
        line-height: 1.3;
      }
      .Text4 {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: monospace;
        margin-top: -27px;
        line-height: 1.3;
      }
      .Text3 {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: monospace;
        margin-top: -30px;
        line-height: 1.3;
      }
      .Text2point5 {
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: monospace;
        margin-top: -30px;
        line-height: 1;
      }
      .Text2 {
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: monospace;
        margin-top: -30px;
        line-height: 1;
      }
        .Text {
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: monospace;
        margin-top: -40px;
      }
      .beginMenuText {
        font-size: 45px;
        font-family: monospace;
        margin-top: auto;
        border-bottom: 3px dashed black;
      }
      
      .unmute {
  background-image: url(http://franriavilla.in/images/unmute.png);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mute {
  background-image: url(http://franriavilla.in/images/mute.png);
}
      
      /* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: initial; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 600px; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65); /* Black w/ opacity */
  width: 800px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #94989e;
  margin-top: 8px; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 500px; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  border-radius: 20px;
  z-index: 20000;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #FFF;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -15px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
    </style>
    <script>
      // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .button {
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #6969697a;
        border-color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Way too much code, you should make it [do only what is described in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You want to change textures on `a-frame` primitives (`a-box`, `a-sphere`), or on models ?

Comment: Sorry, it's about my 3rd time posting so I'm pretty new to this, but I mean the <a-mixin> entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching textures can be done in a couple of ways

- aframe primitives, like `<a-box>`, or `<a-sphere>` entities are an easy case. Just change the `material.src` attribute

  ```
  el.setAttribute('material', 'src', newTexture)
  ```
- models can be quite harder to deal, as you need to switch the `mesh.map.texture` property (possibly on all childs, not only one mesh).

  ```
  var mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh')
  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  loader.load( url, (texture) => {
      // onLoad callback
      mesh.material.map = texture
      mesh.material.needsUpdate = true
      this.switch = !this.switch
    }
  )
  ```

---

The Selection might be done in a milion ways.

At first i wanted to store the information about the texture, and access it when a `<a-box>` is clicked, but a simple way would be to have a couple of images

```
<img class=".images" ....>
<img class=".images" ....>
```

and a component on each aframe primitive which would be:

detecting clicks on those images -> storing the information -> using it when we are clicked:

detecting clicks on images:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("images");
Array.from(els).forEach((el) => {
   el.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
      this.selectedTexture = e.target.src
   })
});
```

applying texture when clicked:

```
this.el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!this.selectedTexture) {
  return
  }
  this.el.setAttribute("material", "src", this.selectedTexture)
})
```

---

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsh0gr85/3/) contains all the above. Two boxes are switching textures by themselves, and the rest will apply the selected image as texture.